# how do i let 2 radio buttons each in a a different groupbox act as they are in the same group?

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

well i have 2 radio buttons and each one exist in a different groupbox.
they they act as they are not related to each other.
but i want them to be as they exist in a same form.
is there a method to 2 that ?
i can do that by handling the the click and unchek the other checkbox but i was wondering if there is a better way?
thanks

Update:
currently i have

```
private void c_RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton1.Checked)
         RadioButton2.Checked = false;
}
private void c_RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton2.Checked)
         RadioButton1.Checked = false;
}
```

Update2:
[image]

Comment: it sounds like you want to break common user interface guidelines. expect confused users.

Comment: comment after update: you'll have to handle both RBs, since the changing checked state of the unhandled button will not check/uncheck the other one.

Comment: @Shimmy: added the other function

Comment: @Karl: i am making this software for myself actually, also i dont know how u can judge my ui without even seeing it? i sure have my reasons for such design decision.

Comment: @karl: i uploaded a screen shot, u can tell me how i can implement this ui in a better way without placing the radio buttons in a different group boxes :)

Comment: The groupbox is a semantic device, it gives the user a mental image of what's going on.  Each group should be one action, and it doesnt make sense to have mutually exclusive choices across two actions. Combine the include/exclude lists into a single actor list and have the radiobuttons just swap which verb is active when accept is clicked.

Comment: i think it will be more confusing if i combine the include/exclude list. and i dont think i need to do that only so that the radio buttons are included in the same groupbox. there is exception to every rule. also ur method will limit the functionally of the application. since i want the user to be able to include movies that have certain actor but not include another one. same argument here , i dont think that to honor the fact that groupbox is a semantic device i need to break the functionnality of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one set of radio buttons, you can fake the UI out by placing them at the form level instead of inside of separate group boxes.

To do this in visual studio you will have to manually edit the designer generated code. Or place the radio buttons outside of the form and use your arrow keys to place it in the correct location.

You have to do this because once you drag the radio button with your mouse the designer will place it inside of the group box.